# Join letters to 1 word

Tags: javascript, peg, pegjs

I'm playing around with [PEG.js](http://pegjs.org/online).

This is my grammar:

```
start = expression

expression = a:[a-z]+
{return a.join("");}
```

When I execute it in my browser:

```
obj = parser.parse("test");
for (var i = 0; i <= obj.length; i++) {
    console.log(i + " - " + obj[i])
}
```

I get this output:

```
0 - t
1 - e
2 - s
3 - t
4 - undefined
```

Why isn't it joined to only 1 word, even though I used `return a.join("")` in my grammar?

Comment: Best guess: `parser.parse()` returns a string. What is the loop supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

`parser.parse` *does* return the single word `"test"`; you are just printing it one character at a time.

Did you mean to do this?

```
var result = parser.parse("test");
console.log(result) // "test"
```

Answer (score 1):

To directly answer your question, you're getting one letter each iteration because a string acts like an array. So you're accessing one letter at a time by using `obj[i]` Try this to get one word returned.

```
obj = parser.parse("test");
for (var i = 0; i <= obj.length; i++) {
    console.log(i + " - " + obj)
}
```